# get previous day google trends in php

Tags: php

Hi
I need previous day google trends to be stored in db. I knew  http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/hourly will get you hourly trends, but i need a whole previous day trends.
if we store hourly trends there may be repeated entries that's why am asking this.
Any one know how to do it in php? Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fetch the ranking hourly and then you calculate the avarage rank and order by that. this is more the around-the-corner-thought-answer to your question, I know, but some thuinking has to be left to you and what's the (technichal) problem, anyway?

Comment: Yes.. it'll be like this,checking an entry for that trend before updating trend list is an option. but i just tried if there is any other way exists... any way nice tip Raffael1984

Comment: so how about voting my reply up ... :-)

Answer (score 1):

This post describes Google Trends PHP API for Hourly Updates:
http://blog.teamgrowth.net/index.php/search-engine-optimization/google-trends-php-api-for-hourly-updates